# Open web page inside iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, ios5

I have application with 6 buttons on start screen. My problem is that I want to open web page clicking on those buttons. I have a code like this:

```
  - (IBAction) accomodation: (id) sender
{
    NSString *webPage1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webPage1];
//    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        [self beginNavigationWith:2 andTitle:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"icn_txt_accomodations", LANGID, nil) andMap:nil andHtml:nil withIdTagsAroundMe: 1 withWeb:url];
}
```

This is method for initializing one of buttons. After that I have method:

```
 - (void) beginNavigationWith: (int) navID andTitle:(NSString*) aTitle andMap:(NSString*) map andHtml:(NSString*) html withIdTagsAroundMe:(int)id_tags withWeb: (NSURL*) webPage
{
    // DIRECT LINK

    if (html != nil) {
        if ([html hasPrefix:@"{ID}"]) {
            NSError *error;

            int res_id = [[html substringFromIndex:4] intValue];
            NSLog(@"DIRECT ID From start>> %d", res_id);

            NSFetchRequest* reqForRestaurant = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *resEntity2 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Restaurant" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            [reqForRestaurant setEntity:resEntity2];

            NSString *stringRes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"res_id.intValue == %d", res_id];
            NSPredicate *resPredicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringRes];
            [reqForRestaurant setPredicate:resPredicate2];

            NSArray *array3 = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:reqForRestaurant error:&error];


            //NSLog(@">>>> Gallery:%d", [managedObject.res_gallery intValue]);

            if (array3 != nil) {
                //NSLog(@"Restaurants count=%d", [array2 count]);
                if ([array3 count] == 1) {

                    Restaurant *managedObjectRes = (Restaurant*) [array3 objectAtIndex:0];

                    RestaurantDetails *details = [[RestaurantDetails alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
                    details.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
                    details.parentID = navID;
                    details.title = managedObjectRes.res_title;
                    [details initItemsWithData:managedObjectRes];   
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
                                }
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    // STANDARD NAV o puro HTML



    NavTableView *navTable = [[NavTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    navTable.title = aTitle;
    navTable.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    navTable.selectQuery = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nav_parent_id.intValue == %d", navID]; // parent id == 0 is ROOT
    //added for use around me
    navTable.id_tags_arroundme = id_tags;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navTable animated:YES];

    if (html != nil) [navTable addHtmlHeader:html];
    if (map != nil) [navTable addActiveMap:map];

    //WEB PAGE

    if ( webPage != nil ) {

        NSString *webPage1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webPage1];
        NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

    }



}
```

This way I manage to open web page but in Saffari and I want it inside application.
Can someone give me a way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: take uiweb view and load this url to view

Comment: On a related note, is this allowed by Apple? During the review that is. I've got a app requirement where I need to open Instagram from an app which has nothing to do with Instagram. Will Apple have a prob with it? Using a UIWebView instead of opening it in Safar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a UIWebView which you can add as a subview to any other view and then call 'loadRequest' on with your URL.

Comment: On a related note, is this allowed by Apple? During the review that is. I've got a app requirement where I need to open Instagram from an app which has nothing to do with Instagram. Will Apple have a prob with it? Using a UIWebView instead of opening it in Safari?